# Oracle dbms_crypto problema con datos number

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, datatables, oracle-11g, encriptación

Soy nuevo en esto de encriptar tablas de base de datos, recién me pidieron encriptar las columnas de una tabla he buscado tutoriales y he encontrado una solución pero me percate de que no funciona para los tipos de datos de tipo number me sale el error SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

unicamente esta funcionado con varchar2 ya intente de todo pero no he podido encontrar la solución y los días prácticamente los estoy agotando espero me puedan ayudar.

les dejo los pasos que realizo para encriptar la columna de mi tabla que funciona con varchar2.

1.- creo el paquete con las funciones para encriptar y desencriptar

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CRYPTIT IS
FUNCTION ENCRYPT_DATA(P_DATA IN VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
FUNCTION DECRYPT_DATA(P_DATA IN RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC;
end cryptit;
```

2.- resto de la función

```
create or replace package body cryptit is
  v_key raw(128) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('testkey1');
  function encrypt_data(p_data in varchar2) return raw deterministic
  is
  l_data raw(2048):= utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_data);
  l_encrypted raw(248);
  begin
  null;
  l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt
  (src => l_data,
            typ => dbms_crypto.des_cbc_pkcs5,
  key => v_key);
  return l_encrypted;
  end encrypt_data;
  function decrypt_data(p_data in raw) return varchar2 deterministic
  is
  l_decrypted raw(2048);
  begin
  l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
  (src => p_data,
          typ => dbms_crypto.des_cbc_pkcs5,
  key => v_key);
 return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_decrypted);
   end decrypt_data;
   end cryptit;
```

3.- aplico update a mi tabla indicando la columna a encriptar

```
update clientes set codigo=cryptit.encrypt_data(codigo);
```

mi tabla tiene la siguiente estructura

```
create table CLIENTES(
usuario NUMBER,
CODIGO varchar2(20));

insert into CLIENTES values (23,'ADEL123');
insert into CLIENTES values (37,'MIQWE76');
insert into CLIENTES values (89,'CVXCV87');
```

al ejecutar el update se reliza con exito se encripta la columna codigo, el problema que tengo es al realizar el update con la columna usuario que es de tipo number he intentado de todo pero no he podido darle solución espero y me puedan ayudar se agradecera mucho 
dejo el update con la sentencia para la columna usuario,

```
update clientes set usuario=cryptit.encrypt_data(usuario);
```